# How can I implement resource synchronization across multiple ServiceStack service calls split among multiple services?

Tags: transactions, locking, servicestack

I would like to create a set of ServiceStack services, hosted within the same host application, that will all use a shared set of file resources. To prevent conflicts, I intend to create synchronization code (aka locking) to prevent read/write conflicts on the files.

If I only wanted to lock a file for the duration of a single service method call, the solution is straightforward. For example, I could create a synchronized global object that tracks locks by Session Key. However, I want a client application to be able to lock a file resource for the duration of MULTIPLE calls to different methods in different ServiceStack services.

What is the best way to accomplish this (OR is this one of those questions where people will tell me I shouldn't be doing that)?

Here's what I've considered so far:

1. If I could share a single ISession object among multiple ServiceStack services, I could track file locks based on the Session key. But I have not been able to find anyway to do that. This needs to work with a C# client using JsonServiceClient objects, there will be one such object for each ServiceStack service, and they each generate a separate ISession on the service end.
2. If I implemented authentication, I could track locks by the authenticated user ID, but two separate people might use the same login in which case they cannot share resource locks.
3. I could combine all my service methods into a single service which would then share a single session. That would mean creating a complex request object which would be a combination of several possible requests. This may not be the awful kludge that it sounds like. The request object could be a query string written in a custom SQL language and my service would parse and run the query. I don't want to do this because it's a LOT more coding work (though if anyone knows a free, robust parsing tool for custom SQL languages, I might consider it).
4. Create a Transaction service that doles out Transaction IDs. If the client wants to hold a lock, it must first get a transaction ID from the Transaction service and pass this ID in with every subsequent service call (it would be an optional property in each request class). This is really not much different than sharing a session (or rather, a session key) between services, but I am making the client do some of the work. Feh.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit lost on what you mean by services, you can have multiple with a single app host, and using the session mechanism will allow you to share a particular client session between services.  Sessions in service stack use the `ICacheClient` you have registered, so if you have, say a server farm, you can use something like the `RedisCacheClient` to share your session info between multiple servers running the same app host.  If you want to lock a file you can store this info in the `ICacheClient` as well.  so you could do something like:

```
public class FileLock
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string FileId { get; set; }
}

public class FileLockService : Service
{
    public object Post(FileLock req)
    {
        // this will only be added to the cache if it doesn't exist
        // but understand that the cache key needs to be unique
        // within the entire system, so qualify it with a urn...
        var wasAbleToLock = Cache.Add("file:lock:" + req.FileId, req.ClientId);

        return wasAbleToLock;
    }

    public object Get(FileLock req)
    {
        // return the client id for who ever has the lock
        return Cache.Get("file:lock:" + req.FileId);
    }
}
```

Comment: By "service" I mean an instantiation of a class implementing ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Service. 

The nub is, how do I get two separate Services to "share a particular client session?" I don't know how to do that. Within a single C# client program, if I call two separate services with two separate JsvServiceClient objects, they each generate their own Session automatically.

Comment: I see what you are getting at, you actually want to share session state between clients. I assume you do some sort of authentication on the clients.  If so, simply get the common key between the sessions, something like `UserId` and use that to lock the file. Now if you only have a single client, but are making multiple calls, you can use the same `JsonServiceClient` multiple times. Often when doing integration testing, I create a service client, make an auth call, (it stores the session cookies internally) and then make several other calls using the same client.